# REACT app gives CSP header error and stops accessing my flask backend endpoints

Tags: reactjs, flask, linker, header, content-security-policy

I have a flask backend hosted on render, its a very simple, the endpoints work in both browser and in postman. I'm new to REACT and I'm trying to access those endpoints in a REACT app I'm working on, everything works fine in local host but when I host the app on any platform (I've tried aws, vercel and render, currently hosted on render), it gives me the following problem.
Normally if I go to the app and go with normal flow (landing page -> login -> dashboard) it all works fine, however the moment I try to access a page directly (login or dashboard page) I get a CSP error.

Refused to connect to 'https://<RENDER_ENDPOINT>/fetch_all_data' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

This error only occurs when I access the page directly and not when I follow the normal structure.

Following are the things I tried

- Add CSP header in a file called customSecurity.js and tried doing customSecurity.get instead of axios.get (asked from chatGPT)

> `import axios from "axios"
>
> const axiosInstance = axios.create({
> headers: { 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self' *.onrender.com/*", },
>
> > });
>
> export default axiosInstance`

- Changed my backend to only provide dummy data, I thought since my backend fetches data from different sources and some of them are only HTTP and not HTTPS I should change it and get just plain textual dummy data.

This might be a small issue like CSP is not being set properly but I'm new to REACT and can't find out what's the exact issue. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code and replace "Your Data Here" with the actual data you want to return :

```
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/fetch_all_data')
def fetch_all_data():
    # Your code to fetch and return data
    response = Response("Your Data Here")
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self' render.com;"
    return response
```

Make sure that your Flask backend is sending the appropriate CSP headers in its response. You can set the CSP header in your Flask application to allow requests to the Render endpoint. remebember to clear your browser cache when testing changes to CSP policies, as cached policies may affect your results. Additionally, consult the documentatation for the specific hosting platforms you're using (AWS, Vercel, Render) to see if they have any additional CSP-related requiremetnts or configurations.